# Returning Multiple QuerySets in Json Dictionaries via Ajax

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am returning my model as a dictionary from my views.py via the following code

```
data = serializers.serialize('json', response_dict)
return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/javascript')
```

The thing is that I have a foreign key that in the object and I want the actual value of the object that the foreign key points to, but I just get the ID. I want to try to return the corresponding objects for the ID. One way I have tried is to return a separate list with the corresponding objects for each foreign key with the following code, but it does not work.

```
    #original dictionary that returns id values for foreign keys
data1 = serializers.serialize('json', response_dict)
    #The corresponding objects from the foreign key table stored in a parallel list of equal length to response_dict
data2 = serializers.serialize('json', other_list)

data = simplejson.dumps([data1, data2])
#return json dump to template via ajax 
return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/javascript')
```

How would I go about returning both the initial dictional and list with corresponding values for the foreign key? I am also open to a better method that gets me the actual object values for each foreign key

Comment: what's in response_dict?

Comment: response_dict =  models.Dishes.objects.filter(type=this_type). It is a dictionary, a filtered subset of a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a way to serialize relations.

Have a look at:

https://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/wiki/DjangoFullSerializers#Relations

Also note that simplejson is deprecated as of Django 1.5:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18023#comment:10

I created a version of the Wad of stuff serializer that works with Django 1.5 a while ago:

https://github.com/kolben/wadofstuff

Answer (score 0):

Eventually in my Django serializer I set use_natural_keys=True and defined the natural keys for the tables whose values I wanted to see. See the tutorial in the Django docs here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#natural-keys

This solution works for my specific purposes, but is limited in general. I marked sunn0's answers as the accepted answer because the 'wadofstuff' serializer in this link seems to give a more extensive and general solution.